# cant get Ajax response values

Tags: javascript, ajax

I get the below response from an ajax call, but when I try to console.log the values it returns undefined

when i console.log(data) is returns the following code.

> `{ "status": false, "message": "video call must be 11 digits long" }`

but the other console.log values returns undefined...see below...I want to pick the status and the content of the message and log it to console.

```
ajax.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data['message']);
}
```

LOG

> `{ "status": false, "message": "video call must be 11 digits long" }`

this is my content type 'Content-Type: application/json',

Comment: Can you please add the actual log of the `data`? I am suspecting that the `data` is a json array.

Comment: I have added the log..{ "status": false, "message": "video call must be 11 digits long" }

Comment: The output from the browser console doesn't always translate very well to text. Could you provide a screenshot (you can paste them directly into the [question editor](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58481566/edit))

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
 dataType: "json"
```

to your request's params or

```
let response = JSON.parse(data); 
console.log(response.status);
```

Comment: Question isn't tagged with [tag:jquery] but your second part is probably what OP needs

Comment: same result...but how do i pick the others values nw...cos they still return undefined

Comment: let response = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(response.status);

Comment: now code doesnt work when i add that like this  ajax.done(function (data) {

                    let response = JSON.parse(data); 
                    console.log(response.status);

Comment: Could you please post full listing of your ajax code?

Comment: let response = JSON.parse(data); console.log(response.status); ...THIS WORKS NOW...Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

let response = JSON.parse(data); console.log(response.status);

This works..thanks to everyone for your help